# I have a code with several plots. How do I know from which part of the code a specific plot comes from(Matlab)?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a code with several plots. How do I know from which part of the code a specific plot comes from.?

The code is produced in Matlab.

Comment: Run it line by line

Comment: Give them titles

Answer (score 0):

I assume the plots appear in different figure windows? New figure windows are created using the `figure` command. I would try searching for `figure` commands in the code; they will be followed by `plot`, `bar`, `stair`, `stem` or any other MATLAB plotting function. You can use breakpoints to run the code line-by-line and see the plots appear.